# Word for ubiquitous and seemingly unimportant?

Tags: single-word-requests

I need a word to describe something that is ubiquitous and seemingly unimportant (even though it's actually quite important).

Example:

> Despite its [word], music is influential in affecting mood, making it a perfect tool to use in therapy.

Comment: I could probably come up with a phrase rather than a single word. Let's see ... how about "apparent levity."

Comment: 'Prosaicness' means both being commonplace and being banal, but doesn't sit well with 'music'.

Comment: It's an intriguing question, but I submit that the example given is slightly at odds with the subject line. The subject implies that the sought-after word *itself* should imply importance. Thus the example sentence is being redundant and diluting the nuance of the word: *"Despite its seeming-unimportance-but-actual-importance, music is actually important."*

Comment: Are you looking for an adjective or a noun?  Despite its [noun] seems hard to find a smooth solution.  I can imagine something like *Despite **being** mostly **recreational**, music is influential in affecting mood*...

Comment: If I substitute the meaning you are after, from your title, rather than the word (something you should do), it makes no sense: *Despite its **being ubiquitous and seemingly unimportant, but actually being very important**, music is influential in affecting mood, making it a perfect tool to use in therapy.* It appears to contradict itself in more than one way. Is the meaning *despite that it seems important* or *despite that it actually is important*? Does one of these point to it being important for use in therapy?

Comment: The example is a bit weird, but the word that I think would work the best there is actually a bit different from your definition: *familiarity*.

Comment: Who considers music unimportant?

Comment: People usually say 'innocuous' before they belie the actual importance of something.

Answer (score 1):

The subject line asks a somewhat different question than the body. The best word I can think of that captures the *feel* of "ubiquitous and seemingly unimportant, but actually very important" is **basic**:

From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/basic):

> **1 a :** of, relating to, or forming the base or essence : fundamental - *basic truths*
> **2 :** constituting or serving as the basis or starting point - *a basic set of tools*

That same page also gives some example sentences:

- She lacks even the most *basic* skills necessary for the job.
- The motel is comfortable but pretty *basic*: you get the necessities all right, but no luxuries.

So it possesses the duality of "so simple that it can be dismissed" yet "so essential that it cannot be ignored".

As for your example sentence, you've constructed it so that you need a noun (the subject line asks for an adjective), and you've also reiterated the "actually important" part in the rest of the sentence, which means you don't really need all the nuance in the sought-after word. You can just go for a noun that means "the quality of being ubiquitous and seemingly unimportant". I would actually argue that would make the sentence more effective, as well as opening you up to more options. For instance:

- Despite its *ubiquity*, music is influential in affecting mood, making it a perfect tool to use in therapy.
- Despite its *banality*, music is influential in affecting mood, making it a perfect tool to use in therapy.
- Despite its *mundanity*, music is influential in affecting mood, making it a perfect tool to use in therapy.

Comment: "Basicness" would be a good answer, if it were a word... .  The OP needs to address the difference between the 'Question' and the 'sample sentence' (that you highlight).

Comment: @Dan - I would say it's a word. Despite not being listed in most dictionaries (at least, it's not in any of the dictionaries that I routinely consult), it's a well-understood construction, it's in several "less academic" dictionaries (like YourDictionary, Urban Dictionary, and Wiktionary), and it's definitely used quite commonly. I did deliberately sidestep its use in my answer, though.

Answer (score 0):

***Familiarity***, perhaps?  (*Knowledge of a thing or person through long or close association or frequent perception by any of the senses; everyday acquaintance, habituation*, OED).

Consider how "*familiarity breeds contempt*" is used to suggest that (excessive) intimacy/informality/habituation to a thing or person can lead to disrespect/disdain (OED).

Comment: 'Familiarity', like 'prosaicness',  doesn't convey 'importance'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - no it doesn't.  I support John Y's comment and am   answering the sample sentence rather than the headline question.

Comment: The question is indeed highly flawed. I've close-voted.